# Creating UML State machine Diagram showing all states of an automated booth

Tags: uml, diagram, state-machine

I have never created/understood completely how to create a state machine diagram based on detailed description so I wanted to start somewhere. The automated booth is for student to return books automatically.

Description:

> To return a book, it must be placed on a small conveyor belt and then the user needs to press the check-in button on the touch screen.
>
> The chip reader in the machine then detects which book is being returned.
> If no book is detected, the conveyor belt returns the item to the user. If a book is detected, the screen displays all the loan information on the screen and the user can confirm the return or cancel it.
>
> If cancelled, the book is returned to the user. If confirmed, the book is taken into the library and the booth prints a physical receipt for the user. Additionally, the machine has a maintenance mode; no books can be returned until the maintenance is completed.

The Diagram:
[image]

I am not sure if I am describing all the states that the machine has or if I am fundamentally missing the guide lines of state machine diagram rules. I would appreciate any feedback as I am still learning.

Comment: That looks more like an activity diagram. The booth just looks like having 2 states: idle and verifying book (and the accepting o rejecting). There is nothing said about maintenance stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most cases, a state is a situation in which nothing happens and the machine is waiting for an external event to happen. The event may then be a reason to go to another state. Along the transition arrow, you write `event [ condition ] / action`. In your case, `event` is something the user does and `action` is something the machine does in response to the event.

States in which the machine is waiting are in your case: "Idle", "Loan information displayed" and "Maintenance". Although "Out of service" and "Self test" seem logical states, the description does not mention them, so I would not include them.

In some cases, you may wish to use a state to reflect the situation that the machine is busy doing something. The `event` may then be the completion of the work or an external interruption. In your case,  `Scan for book` may be such a state, but you could also regard scanning as an action, for example `user presses button / scan for book`.

Both options are valid, but let's choose for `Scan for book` as a state (although I think "Busy scanning" would be a more state-like name).

From the description, I assume the machine goes from `Idle` to `Scan for book` when the user presses the button. So instead of `Request book [check-in button pressed]`, I would write `user presses check-in button`.

State `Scan for book` is left when the machine has finished scanning. Along the arrow towards the decision diamond, you could write `finished scanning`. If it is a valid book, the machine will show the loan information and enter the state `Loan information displayed`. This transition is `[valid book] / display loan information`. Alternatively, you could write `display loan information` as an entry action inside the `Loan information displayed` state.

If the item is not valid, the machine returns the item. The transition is `[else] / return item` and this transition goes from the diamond to the `Idle` state.

In the same way, you can model transitions between `Idle` and `Maintenance` and between `Idle` and `Loan information displayed`.